# strict difference between two dates in R lubridate

Tags: r

I have the following code using lubridate in R:

`interval("2022-01-20","2022-02-01")  %/% months(1)`

`answer:0`

But the answer I'm looking for is "1" instead of 0

Comment: How about `month("2022-02-01") - month("2022-01-20")`?

Comment: The problem with that approach is if I have different years (for example, 2021-02-01 instead of 2022) the answer will be 1 instead of 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to get 1 month difference, we may need to `floor`, otherwise it is just 12 days and it is still less than a month

```
library(lubridate)
interval(floor_date(as.Date("2022-01-20"), 
        "month"),as.Date("2022-02-01")) %/% months(1)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ceiling(interval("2022-01-20","2022-02-01") / months(1))
```